# Writing an (efficient) CachedMap implementation

Tags: java

I'm attempting to write cached versions of `java.util`'s Map implementations, wherein upon constructing the map instance you can specify an expiration time for the keys or values, e.g.

```
public CachedMap(long keyMS, long valueMS) {
    //...
}
```

My thought to do this was to simply extend the relevant `Map` classes and override their `Entry` classes to add a "set" timestamp for checking expiry, however it seems that those classes have package-private protection. Short of injection or maintaining two more internal maps just for time, is there any way I can go about adding functionality to those classes (or an alternative solution that won't add relatively extreme overhead)? Or will I end up having to rewrite all of `java.util`'s Map implementations?

As for the purpose of this, initially it's for storing automatically expiring cached objects retrieved from a database, however there are other applications where these Map implementations would be useful for me.

Comment: There is al [existing implementation](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap), why not reuse it?

Comment: You shouldn't *extend* a Map. You should *use* one. But you should also avoid reinventing the wheel. Guava has a good cache implementation, and much more to offer: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: @fge that's only a `ConcurrentMap`, I'm wanting implementations for `HashMap` and `TreeMap` as well.

Comment: @Rogue in that case I suggest you read one of the many implementations and modify it for your needs.  Note: ConcurrentHashMap is a hash map.